# PHP prevent html entity creation at string concatenation

Tags: php, string, concatenation, html-entities

How can i prevent that PHP converts a recognized part of a string to an html-entity?

So e.g. lets say i have to concat parts together to an url, like:

```php
echo '&' . 'section=' . '<br>';

$a = '&a';
$b = 'mplitude=';
echo "{$a}{$b}" . '<br>';

echo sprintf("%s%s", '&quote', '=');
```

the code above prints the following:

```
§ion=
&litude=
"e=
```

instead of:

```
&section=
&amplitude=
&quote=
```

how can this be prevented without throwing filters on it trying to convert the symbols back to an string again?

Answer (score 1):

You need using **htmlspecialchars** function:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('&' . 'section=' . '<br>');
```